# Spring boot: Jersey ResourceConfig needs annotating?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey

I am just getting started with Spring Boot and I wanted to implement a ResourceConfig and I finding some conflicting ideas.

Take the following

```
@Component
public class JerseyExampleConfig extends ResourceConfig {
```

The above is annotated with COMPONENT

```
@Configuration
public class JerseyExampleConfig extends ResourceConfig {
```

Which one is correct?

I thought annotating with Configuration would be the correct way but it appears that the Component is used in examples.

Any ideas ?

Whats the difference?

Comment: This is confusing as `configuration` does sound correct here - but the `Configuration` that comes with spring has nothing to do with Jersey. Spring recognises the bean and registers it correctly (and bridges DI). You *can* use `Configuration`, however you would define a `Bean` annotated method that returns your Resource config. Effectively this does the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jersey) suggests `@Component`:

> To get started with Jersey 2.x just include the `spring-boot-starter-jersey` as a dependency and then you need one `@Bean` of type `ResourceConfig` in which you register all the endpoints:
>
> ```java
> @Component
> public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
>
>     public JerseyConfig() {
>         register(Endpoint.class);
>     }
> }
> ```

The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jersey) also says the following:

> You can also register an arbitrary number of beans implementing `ResourceConfigCustomizer` for more advanced customizations.
>
> All the registered endpoints should be `@Component`s with HTTP resource annotations (`@GET` etc.), e.g.
>
> ```java
> @Component
> @Path("/hello")
> public class Endpoint {
>
>     @GET
>     public String message() {
>         return "Hello";
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Since the `Endpoint` is a Spring `@Component` its lifecycle is managed by Spring and you can `@Autowired` dependencies and inject external configuration with `@Value`. The Jersey servlet will be registered and mapped to `/*` by default. You can change the mapping by adding `@ApplicationPath` to your `ResourceConfig`.

Comment: For the Resource class, is it `Component` or `Controller` - i thought `Controller` was the right Spring-ish way but am not too sure. It achieves the same result (might add support in case one would want to ditch jersey and switch to the spring way of doing REST)?

Comment: @pandaadb Honestly I never tested with `@Controller`. But `@Controller` is a specialization of `@Component`. May work.

Answer (score 1):

So even if you can not decide which to use for `JerseyConfig` you can determinate which is the better in a situation by reading what they actually mean:

> @Configuration Indicates that a class declares one or more @Bean
>   methods and may be processed by the Spring container to generate bean
>   definitions and service requests for those beans at runtime
>
> @Component Indicates that an annotated class is a "component". Such
>   classes are considered as candidates for auto-detection when using
>   annotation-based configuration and classpath scanning.
>
> @Configuration is meta-annotated with @Component, therefore
>   @Configuration classes are candidates for component scanning

So by the said above you can annotate your config class with `@Configuration` as well but it will be an unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 1):

They both make the `ResourceConfig` a Spring Bean, which is all that's really required to make the Spring Boot-Jersey integration work. You could even just do

```
@SpringBootApplication
class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String... args) {}

    @Bean
    public ResourceConfig jerseyConfig() {
        return new MyResourceConfig();
    }
}
```

With this, you wouldn't need `@Component` or `@Configuration`. It simply makes the `ResourceConfig` a Spring Bean, which like I said, is all that is required.

That being said, between the two annotations, `@Configuration` is really meant for Spring configuration. You *could* place your Spring configuration in the `ResourceConfig` subclass, but I would just put it in a separate configuration class, just to keep things separate. Note that configuration classes are also Spring Beans, so that's why the `@Configuration` works.

`@Component` on the other hand, is a general purpose annotation that will make the class a Spring Bean. This is the reason all the the examples show using the annotation, as the `ResourceConfig` is generally not meant to be a Spring configuration class, and it is less verbose then the example above, not using any annotations.